# django - view returning no value?

Tags: python, django

I have the following basic views.py to test out doing queries based on the user.

```
def Vendor_Matrix(request):
    username = request.session.get('username','')
    queryset = User.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('user_permissions', 'username', 'first_name')
    return JSONResponse(queryset)
```

I'm logged in (using Mezzanine) into my site.  I then have that view referenced in the following urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from api import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^your-data/vendor-matrix/$', 'api.views.Vendor_Matrix'),
)
```

When I go to the URL it comes up with a blank page.  specifically this -

```
[]
```

I can only imagine it's not registering the logged in user?

I've simplified my views.py even further - Definitely not registering the username that is logged in.  It still returns nothing.

```
def Vendor_Matrix(request):
    username = request.session.get('username','')
    return HttpResponse(username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's not where Django keeps the logged-in user...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

```
return JSONResponse(operator.attrgetter('user_permissions', 'username', 'first_name')(request.user))
```

Comment: you're right in that I was looking in the wrong place.  I got this to work so I'm understanding now how to do my queryset.  def index(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
    return HttpResponse(username)